Running Renovatebot to update maven dependencies
I have been reading extensively about renovate to automate dependency updates. but i somehow am not able to grasp the idea.
My project is a maven project in gitlab.
The renovate documentation says there are three ways to run renovate:

as npm package
docker image
as Mend Renovate app.

infact a 4th way, clone the renovate codebase I also found that mend renovate app is not supported in gitlab.
My question: is the npm package method supported only for npm projects?
So how do i run renovate my project?
I am new to gitlab as well, been banging my head. any direction would be of great help!

For Gitlab it is the best way to introduce renovate as a Gitlab runner. The you can trigger the runner whenever you want. E.g. manually or time scheduled.

Run it as a Gitlab CI job using the container image. See https://medium.com/@gaeljw/running-renovate-on-premise-28d946e01777 for some guidelines for instance.
